# scaling 1st order quasilinear PDE and method of characteristics

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\alpha:\mathbb R^n\to (0,\infty)$, $b:\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^n$ and $c:\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be smooth functions. Then the differential equations $$ b(x,u(x))Du(x)+c(x,u(x))=0 \quad\mathrm{in}\ \mathbb R^n$$ and $$ b_\alpha (x,u(x))Du(x)+c_\alpha(x,u(x))=0\quad\mathrm{in}\ \mathbb R^n$$ (with $b_\alpha(x,z)=\alpha(x)b(x,z)$ and $c_\alpha$ accordingly) have the same solutions $u$.

Using the method of characteristics we obtain the characteristic equations \begin{align*}\tag{$*$}
\frac{dz}{ds} & = -\alpha(x) c(x,z) \\
\frac{dx}{ds} & = \alpha(x)b(x,z)
\end{align*}

for the scaled PDE and 
\begin{align*}\tag{$**$}
\frac{dz}{ds} & = - c(x,z) \\
\frac{dx}{ds} & = b(x,z)
\end{align*}

for the original PDE. It is known that solutions $(x,z) = (x(s),z(s))$ of these characteristic systems are solutions of the PDE, $u(x) = z(x(s))$.

Now I am wondering: How are the solutions of $(*)$ and $(**)$ connected? In other words: If I calculate a solution $(x_\alpha,z_\alpha)$ of the characteristic system for the scaled PDE, can I obtain a solution $(x,z)$ of $(**)$ from it?

I thought that maybe I can scale $s$ by introducing another map $t$, and considering $x(t(s))$. This got me to $$\frac{du}{ds} = \frac{du}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{dt}{ds}$$ and thus by comparing this with the original PDE\begin{align*}
\frac{dt}{ds} & = \alpha(x(t(s))) \\
\mathrm{s.t.} \quad t(0) & = 0
\end{align*}

But I do not know how to proceed. Can I solve this for $t$ and is this even the right way? I'd appreciate any advice on this. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the solutions of (\*\*) are just the solutions of (\*) after a change of parameter. This is evident on geometric grounds: each system prescribes a vector field to which solutions must be everywhere tangent, and in your case both fields are collinear. But finding the reparametrization explicitly is likely to be quite difficult. I would rather use the solution of (\*) as is, plugging it into the PDE and investigating the behavior of $u(x(s),z(s))$ as a function of $s$.

Comment: So you don't think that it's too difficult to find the reparametrization even for this relatively easy PDE? I'll try that method you suggested, even though I'd really like to find a reparametrization. Thanks!

Comment: For example, the cubic parabola $y=x^3$ is a pretty simple curve, but its arclength parametrization is complicated.